# DateTime.yesterday returns today's date instead of yesterday

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
1.9.3p0 :020 > DateTime.now
 => Mon, 02 Jan 2012 21:10:36 -0500 
1.9.3p0 :021 > DateTime.yesterday
 => Mon, 02 Jan 2012
```

I am pretty confused why this is happening. Any idea? Today is supposed to be Jan 2, and yesterday is Jan 1.

Also this is weird.

```
1.9.3p0 :023 > 1.days.ago
 => Mon, 02 Jan 2012 02:20:22 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: `Tue, 03 Jan 2012 02:26:47 UTC +00:00`. OMG Future date is returned!

Comment: look at the timezone - I presume you're not living in europe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to set your timezone.  try this:

```
> z = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" 
 => "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" 
> 0.days.ago.in_time_zone(z)
 => Mon, 02 Jan 2012 18:37:50 PST -08:00
```

Then add something like this to application.rb:

```
 config.time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```